# react-native navigation route undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

When starting my app I have an error:
Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.title')

I was expecting the navigator to initialise with the 'Setup' route as I am  initalRoute={{ title: 'Setup'}}

how to I make route defined, on initial app load?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';

import SetupComponent from './src/setup/setup.component';
import HomeComponent from './src/home/home.component';

export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initalRoute={{ title: 'Setup'}}      
        renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
        console.log("routing", route.title);

          if (route.title === 'Setup'){
            return <SetupComponent navigator={navigator} />
          }
          if (route.title === 'Home') {
            return <HomeComponent navigator={navigator} />
          }        
           console.log("return default");
      
        }}
      />        
    
    );
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a typo in the definition of your Navigator component - your code reads `initalRoute` when it should be `initialRoute`. Change this line and you should see that error fixed.